ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.postgresql' on Ubuntu 24.04
Yesterday I switched to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from windows and having an issue with my django project and tried every suggestion on the web but no luck. I'm getting below issue:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'

Most of the suggesion on the web telling update django but I'm already using the latest version 5.0.4
Also postgresql is working fine. I'm able to connect it.

Deleted existing venv and recreated it and it worked. No idea.

The value is django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2, not just django.db.backends.postgresql

Recreating .env worked

@ftdeveloper classic. It is quite weird it works without psycopg2.. I've always used that
